# How do I remove string after or before space in PHP?

Tags: php

How do I remove string after or before space in PHP?

I have a string like $string = "Hello World";

The output should be "Hello"

How can I do that?

I have a string like $string = "Hello World";

The output should be "Hello"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you can explode on `<space>` and take the first element of the resulting array:

```
<?php

$a = "Hello World";
$arr = explode(" ",$a);
echo $arr[0];  // Hello
```

I can't help but think there's more to it than this.